# Internet Explorer 6 : Euro sign not displayed on ajax request

Tags: ajax, utf-8, internet-explorer-6, character-encoding

i'm using jquery 1.4.2 to send an ajax request to a php page then display the result.

**This works fine with FF3 and IE8, but in IE6 the character € is replaced by a square**, i tried to force the character encoding of the php page using header() but it didn t work...

I'm working on windows with Zend Studio for eclipse (projet encoding is utf-8)

here is the ajax call :

```
$.ajax({
  url:'index.php?module=ajax&action=getCommande&no-header=1&id='+id ,
  cache:true,
  success:function(html){
    $("#recap_commande").html(html);
  }
});
```

requested page :

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
echo "Récapitulatif de la demande " . $_GET ['id'] . " (".$this->getTotal($nb["COD_ART"],$nb["COD_OPTION"])." €) ";
?>
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this was a specific computer problem, the euro sign is correctly display on another computer with same OS and IE6 ....

I dont understand where the problem came from , i tried to empty the cache still the same...
when alerting ajax response the € is correctly display, when copy the square character then paste it in notepad i can see the € ! ??

my life will be so much simplier without this stupid ie6!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to avoid concatenating parameters as you did. Use the `data` hash like this so that jQuery take care of properly encoding url values:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php',
    cache: true,
    data: { module: 'ajax', action: 'getCommande', no-header: '1', id: id },
    success: function(html) {
        $('#recap_commande').html(html);
    }
});
```

Also make sure that your pages are [utf-8 encoded](http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/web/tips/declare.html).

Comment: thanks for this tip! i will use data now.
I verified encoding  (using notepad++) it's utf-8 without BOM.

Here is a sample of the firebug headers of the response , encoding seems correct.

    Réponse
    Date Tue, 24 Aug 2010 13:37:34 GMT
    Server Apache/2.2.15 (Win32) DAV/2 SVN/1.6.6
    X-Powered-By PHP/5.3.2 ZendServer

    Transfer-Encoding chunked
    Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8